# JS error, Look inside

Tags: javascript

```
/**
 * @const
 * @type {!storeLocator.FeatureSet}
 * @type {!storeLocator.FeatureSet}
 * @private
 */
MedicareDataSource.prototype.FEATURES_ = new storeLocator.FeatureSet(
    new storeLocator.Feature('Wheelchair-YES', 'Shoe1'),
    new storeLocator.Feature('Audio-YES', 'Shoe2')
);


/**
 * @return {!storeLocator.FeatureSet}
 */
MedicareDataSource.prototype.getFeatures = function() {
    return this.FEATURES_;
};
```

Everytime I go to add a line of code after the `Audio-YES` line the output disappears in my program? What is wrong?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add `,` before inserting the new line `new storeLocator.Feature('something', 'else')`

Comment: I love you. @Mojtaba you are my hero.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not add code right after `new storeLocator.Feature('Audio-YES', 'Shoe2')`. The plot:
`storeLocator.FeatureSet` is a *constructor*, you **do not** write code there, you **pass parameters**, separated by commas.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to add `,` before inserting the new line:

```
MedicareDataSource.prototype.FEATURES_ = new storeLocator.FeatureSet(
    new storeLocator.Feature('Wheelchair-YES', 'Shoe1'),
    new storeLocator.Feature('Audio-YES', 'Shoe2'), // don't forget the comma
    new storeLocator.Feature('something', 'else')
);
```